# Reading array of character

Tags: c, arrays, character, printf, scanf

I made a program in C that reads an array of characters. It didn't work properly.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char a[50];
    int n, i;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
        scanf("%c", a+i);
    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
        printf("%c ", *(a+i));
    return 0;
}
```

This program didn't read the characters I wanted.

For input

```
5
a b c d e
```

program printed

```
 a   b
```

When I changed `scanf("%c", a+i)` to `scanf(" %c", a+i)` it worked fine.

Can somebody explain me why didn't the first code work as I wanted?

Comment: This is C code, not C++....

Comment: You may want to research [`scanf()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf), whitespace consumption, and what trips the latter when using the former.

Comment: Read [Scanf](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scanf.3.html) manual says: *"A sequence of white-space characters (space, tab, newline, etc.; see  isspace(3)). This directive matches any amount of whitespace, including none, in the input."* A good link to learn [C Printf and Scanf Reference](http://wpollock.com/CPlus/PrintfRef.htm)

Comment: also better `scanf("%d\n", &n);` to "eat" buffered new line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`scanf("%c", a+i);` did not work because it consumes the newline left in the `stdin` buffer in the previous `scanf` call. The `%c` conversion specifier in the format string of `scanf` matches a character and the usual skip of leading white space is suppressed. When you add a leading space in the format string of `scanf`

```
scanf(" %c", a + i);
   //  ^ note the leading space
```

means `scanf` will read and discard any number of leading whitespace characters. Thus it works in your case.

Answer (score 0):

Read carefully the documentation of [scanf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scanf.3.html) (which is a standard C function, not idiomatic C++).

In its format string:

> ```
>    ·      A sequence of white-space characters (space, tab, newline,
>           etc.; see isspace(3)).  This directive matches any amount of
>           white space, including none, in the input.
> ```

A more C++ specific way would be to use [operator >>](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/operator%3E%3E/) or the [get](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/get/) member function of [std::istream](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/)

Answer (score 0):

The blank space its also a character. You can refer to the the documentation here :

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/

You were reading new line after 5, 2 chars, 2 spaces.